# MySQL: When To Break Up / Split a Table

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I'm building a database and I'm not sure how deep of a hierarchy I should make.

It seems the best case for space saving would be three layers. 
group->sub_group->item

In average scenarios there are 300 items to a subgroup and 100 subgroups to groups. Items are currently nearing 1 million and growth is accelerating.

I'm attached to distinguishing GROUP from ITEM because it reflects the real world, but SUB_GROUP only exists because ITEMs are usually identical for a few hundred rows. To be clear, I could take the data in one instance of sub group and attach it to every instance of item.

Would making at least 3 joins in every query be better for performance? Or am I better off making less tables with more repetitive data?

Comment: I don't know a time that I have regretted normalizing a table, and plenty of times when not doing so has caused many headaches. Indexes will get you the performance you need.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much a MySQL question as a SQL RDBMS question in general.

You have a database normalized to eliminate duplication and minimize storage.

You may be right to normalize and put the subgroup info with the item if:

1. The subgroup data is small.
2. You often query both subgroup and item information together and view isn't sufficing.
3. You actually have a performance issue that would drive a change--don't prematurely optimize.

There are probably other considerations, but that shoud get you started.

There is not absolute here.

Comment: I think this is steering me towards not making a subgroup table. To clarify, if SUB_GROUP exists, ITEM will never be queried without being joined to SUB_GROUP. Item would basically contain no data. Not having SUB_GROUP would be largely beneficial to viewing/comprehending the database. I'm simply not familiar with how worthwhile it is to save all of that space and if it overcomes the associated headaches in querying.

Comment: That would be the wrong decision, since it allows your data to exist in an incorrect state (the common values in some rows of `items` might get updated and other rows left with their original values -- which is correct?  Structure the data correctly and, if `JOIN`ing the tables together is a common operation encapsulate it in a VIEW.

Comment: Again, it seems correct normalization would be to include the sub_group, but I'm also persuaded by the fact that the inserted data is basically final. Not creating this new layer would be beneficial to generating reports which is all I plan to do with the data. 

I'm still on the fence and it seems the question is: technically correct VS keeping it simple and more real world grounded.

Comment: How much data is stored at the subgroup level? Denormalization is common for reporting/datawarehousing work in which having the data repeated simplifies analysis and speeds retrieval. That's said there using a view to encapsulate the joins or working with them directly should not be considered a headache--its the bread and butter of relational databases.

Comment: The subgroup would hold 5 int values and the item would only point to the subgroup.

Comment: so subgroup is something like (subgroup_id, int1,int2,int3,int4,int5) and items only (item_id,subgroup_id)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. Again, the subgroup comes not out of the real world but out of the fact that many sequential items all have the same data.

Comment: It's not a great deal of space either way. At a million records each int field would cost you ~4MB on the item table so you be adding 5 of those and removing the subgroup_id (int as well) so net change of ~16MB. Personally I would keep the subgroup, I don't think it'll be a problem if you decide to combine the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your decision should not be based, in the first instance, on performance issues, number of JOINs required to retrieve the data, or any related issue.  You should choose the design that *correctly* models your data.  If you're using a relational database to store your data, that means following the principles of data normalization *independent of perceived performance issues*.  Having done that, if you really cannot achieve the performance that you require you can consider limited, strategic denormalizations to get the performance that you need.  In most cases, however, the normalized solution will also be the most performant.

That said, it's not entirely clear to me what "group", "sub-group", and "item" are modelling in the real world.  However, principles of data normalization absolutely state that common values in multiple columns of multiple records in `items` should be abstracted out to a single record in `sub-group`.  What's not clear is whether you can get by with *only* three tables, or whether there are additional levels of grouping that need to be normalized out.